# OSX and OpenGL 4.x compatibility

Tags: macos, opengl, osx-lion, glsl

I'm working on a portable application that should run on OSX-Lion as well.

From what I read [here](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/GLInfo_1072_Core.html) OpenGL/GLSL support seems to be 3.2/150 can someone confirm this?

My application requires **at least** GLSL ver 400. Is there a way to have it running on Lion? Some cards (i.e. ATI HD6770) are OpenGL 4.1 compliant. Does it mean it can go only as far as 3.2/150 under OSX?

Answer (score 2):

confirmed by alternate source, osx opengl 4.x support is still TBA